# Number of sundays between two dates?

Tags: sas

I am having problems with finding the number of sundays between two dates. I tried to use the intck () function to count number of weeks between two dates and since week in SAS starts on a Sunday I thought that was the right way.  However now I am not so sure. 
My dates go from 2007QI to 2013QII. I want to know the number of sundays in each quarter, so I have to look at the number of sundays between current quarter and previous (that is this date and lag (date)). When I use the intck() function I get 13 as the number of weeks in each quarter (except for one where I get 14).. i am not sure whether it is correct to assume that there are 13 sundays in each quarter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intck` is the correct function, but I would use `weekday` as the time interval.  Ordinarily this assumes a 5 day working week, with Saturday and Sunday as weekends, but you can tweak it to use a 1 day working week, with Monday - Saturday as weekends (i.e. just count the number of Sundays).

```
data _null_;
format a b date9.;
a='01 nov 2016'd;
b='18 nov 2016'd;
Sundays = intck('weekday234567w',a,b);
put _all_;
run;
```